# Simple approach to develop an text editing tool for the mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I come from the iPhone development world but have never developed desktop applications.

Now I want to write a small but helpful text editor for helping wiring small articles. I have found that I always summarize knowledge in TextEdit in a raw, not nicely formatted manner. Next, I go through that and start forming useful sentences out of what I have gathered there.

The tool I want to write will have this features:

- the interface is splitted in two main sections, pretty much like an FTP client: On the left there's the actual text to write. On the right there are the raw notes. Both independently scrollable and editable.
- at least the left-side editor should have some basic markup capabilities, similar to TextEdit.

I assume that there is already a good and useful class for doing exactly that. So the question is: Which are good starting points here? Are there any open source projects for mac text editors I could have a look at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextEdit itself is given as an example as part of the developer tools install  see /Developer/Examples/TextEdit

Comment: that's great!! Am I free to modify that code and make something else with it?

Comment: @mystify: Read the Apple license at the top of the source files: "Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the "Apple Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple Software, with or without modifications, in source and/or binary forms;" That's pretty permissive.

Answer (score 0):

> Which are good starting points here?

Read [the Cocoa text system documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/), or [the other Cocoa text system documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/).

You can usually just drop a text view into your window and let it do all the work. You only need to handle loading it with data and saving data from it.